# Spaces in Directory Names

Tags: file, directory, naming

Is putting a space in a directory name still a big deal? I've been doing some reading, but all the articles are from the early 2000s. Is it a problem now?

For those who don't get what I mean: `public_html/space directory/index.html`

If this is still an issue, why shouldn't I use spaces when naming files and directories?

Comment: Are you asking about spaces in filesystem names, or spaces in URL components?

Comment: Filesystem names. I'll adjust my post.

Comment: It's still unclear, especially after reading your comments to Oded's answer, whether you're asking about filesystem paths or those paths as rendered in a URL. Oded's addressing the latter, and Anton's addressing the former.

Comment: I should have said both, I suppose...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spaces in URLs are still special characters that need to be escaped or encoded (either a `+` or `%20`).

Comment: Aside from needing to escape them, are there any hiccups caused by using them?

Comment: @Yoshiyahu - nothing that I am aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am still crossing fingers when executing external processes (from ant or Java's ProcessBuilder for example). If you just pass this dir to the external process within the command - it may break apart in two arguments which is clearly not what you want.

Some quoting and minding the spaces is still required in some usecases.